# Creating Summary Table from R Variables

Tags: r, tabular, summary

I am currently importing a large .csv file of NBA box score summaries.  Each player for each game has its own entry.

I am using the following code to calculate a few different statistics for each unique name within the .csv file.

```
NBA_SD <- NBA %>%
group_by(First..Last) %>%
summarise(sd = sd(DKP))

NBA_MAX <- NBA %>%
group_by(First..Last) %>%
summarise(max = max(DKP))

NBA_MIN <- NBA %>%
group_by(First..Last) %>%
summarise(min = min(DKP))

NBA_MEAN <- NBA %>%
group_by(First..Last) %>%
summarise(mean = mean(DKP))
```

My goal from here is to essentially create a table similar to an Excel spreadsheet with each player name and then the corresponding statistic to the right of the name in a new column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple summary statistics with `summarise`, all on the same data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

NBA %>%
  group_by(First..Last) %>%
  summarise(sd = sd(DKP),
            max = max(DKP),
            min = min(DKP),
            mean = mean(DKP))
```